# SQL: left join query

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am having problems forming an sql query.

Table stucture:

```
 TABLE A:
 id     | data_a 
--------|--------
 1      | data1  
 2      | data2   
 3      | data3   

 TABLE B:
  id     | data_b | a_id 
 --------|--------|--------
  1      | data4  | 1
  2      | data5  | 1
  3      | data6  | 2
  4      | data7  | 3
  5      | data8  | 3

 TABLE C:
  id     | data_c | b_id   | x_id   
 --------|--------|--------|--------
  1      | data9  | 1      | 1
  2      | data10 | 2      | 1
  3      | data11 | 3      | 1
  4      | data12 | 1      | 2
  5      | data13 | 4      | 2
```

Required output:

```
 data_a | data_b | data_c 
--------|--------|--------
 data1  | data4  | data12
 data1  | data5  | 
 data2  | data6  | 
 data3  | data7  | data13
 data3  | data8  |
```

Current sql:

```
SELECT data_a, data_b, data_c
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id 
LEFT JOIN c ON b.id = c.b_id
WHERE c.x_id = 2 OR c.x_id = null;
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05ca9c/1)

Comment: Please add some explanation as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: @shmosel trying to get the required output

Comment: I generally upvote qustions with sql fiddles and downvote questions wth table a, table b, table c. why do you go out of your way to make things difficult?

Comment: @e4c5 I prefer fiddles to, didn't want to get told off for a required part of the question being hosted elsewhere.

Comment: I just explained why I didn't downvote your question for all your a,b,c stuff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the x_id = 2 in left join condition.

```
SELECT
  data_a, 
  data_b, 
  data_c

FROM
  a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
    LEFT JOIN c ON b.id = c.b_id and c.x_id=2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this : -

```
SELECT
  data_a, 
  data_b, 
  data_c

FROM
  (Select data_a,data_b,b.id from a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id) as k
    LEFT JOIN (Select * from c WHERE
  c.x_id = 2 OR c.x_id = null) as j ON k.id = j.b_id
```

for exact match just add this :-

```
order by data_a,data_b
```

Comment: thanks for your help. This does work but wonderbell's answer does not require a nested select statement